# Save SMTP authentication

Tags: php, email, authentication, smtp

I would like to send e-mail through my application in PHP but I also would like to save it in the "Sent" folder for my e-mail account.

What I think is that I need the authentication parameters for authenticate in the server, send the e-mail and it will be saved in the system.

Is it any way to encrypt it or to get a token in order to not to storage the authentication parameters (username / password) in the database of the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP(Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) does not save your 'sent' emails on server. SMTP is only means to send emails - ie. it is a protocol stating how you must talk to the sever to send email.